# Sequelize raw mysql query returning null fields

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have an app that asks users multiple questions. The goal is to not display a question that the user has already answered. So if Bob answers question X he won't ever see it. However, Sally would see question X if she hasn't already answered it.

I have a MySQL query that works just fine inside my query editor. The query joins two tables and returns a question that doesn't match the provided username string or if that username is null (meaning the question hasn't been answered). The problem is inside sequelize if a username string is null the query returns null fields but if a question has been answered by another username it will display the question.

Here is my working query:

```
select * from questions 
left join responses on responses.QuestionId = questions.id 
where responses.username <> 'username string' or responses.username is null
order by rand() limit 1;
```

Here is my sequelize query:

```
_sequelize.query(
'select * from questions ' +
'left join responses on responses.QuestionId = questions.id ' +
'where responses.username <> "' + req.query.name + '" or responses.username  is null ' +
'order by rand() ' +
'limit 1',
{model : models.Responses})
```

Comment: Try adding "logging: console.log" to your Sequelize options so you can see the generated SQL.

Comment: Null Response : Executing (default): select * from questions left join responses on responses.QuestionId = questions.id where responses.username <> "teej" or responses.username is null order by rand() limit 1

Comment: I think you need to reword your question to make it clearer. What do you mean by "the query returns null fields?" Of course most of the fields will be null. Are you saying all of the fields are null? And why would the username field be null? You should be checking for that in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User error. I had my associations wrong so I added a 'beenAnswered' field to the Questions table.